# how to pass arguments to a python function that has variant argument?

Tags: python, c++, boost

i use boost::python to callback a python function at C++ side , the python function may have variant arguments , it looks like :

```
foo(int) ,
foo(int ,double),
foo(string , othertype,...) ,
```

in my C++ program i send foo as a boost::python::object ,

```
void Call(object foo)
{
//check each argument and assign value for example
int arg1=2;
string arg2="hehe";
.....
//then send above arguments to foo , but how to send?
foo(??);
}
```

and now i can get each argument name and give value accordingly , but my problem is : how to pass value to foo ?

i use boost::python::list or tuple to collect data , but doesn't work , argument error . 
anyone can help me ? thank you very much .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a Python function having variant arguments. As far as I can tell, C++-style function overloading is mostly not a thing in Python, with the exception of the implementation of PEP443: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/

Answer (score 0):

```
def myFun(arg1, **kwargs):  
    for key, value in kwargs.items(): 
        print ("%s == %s" %(key, value)) 

# Driver code 
myFun("Hi", first ='Geeks', mid ='for', last='Geeks')
```

you can use **args:
so you can pass multiple arguments with different types as a dict type

you check this link for more info : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/

Comment: thanks for your comment , but i think you misunderstand my intent , i call foo in C++ program , foo function are almost fixed as positional argument , so my question is how to package arguments in C++ and pass them to foo